# CSV Export Highcharts don't work

Tags: highcharts

I have problem with implementing CSV-Export in my Highchart. By the way I wonder why it still does not exist default after half a year working with it :(

I use exactly this code http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/

```
/**
* A small plugin for getting the CSV of a categorized chart
*/
```

But I get two errors!

The first error is in exporting.js **Uncaught TypeError: Object -Object- has no method getOptions**

[image]

Why ??

Best regards!

Susanne :)

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use 1.9.x version of jquery, and then problem should disappear. jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/100/